# Laravel: Extending different layouts inside if-else condition 3 roles

Tags: laravel

I have 3 roles  **user employee** and **admin**

I have this code.

```
    @if(Auth::User()->user_role == 1)
        {{$type = "layouts.admin_layout"}}
    @elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 2)
        {{$type = "layouts.employee_layout"}}
    @elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 3)
        {{$type = "layouts.user_layout"}}
    @endif
```

It gives me 3 layout.

Comment: what is error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't declare a variable using `{{  }}`. this is used for echo/print a variable. Instead `{{  }}` try using `@php #code here @endphp`

```
@if(Auth::User()->user_role == 1)
   @php $type = "layouts.admin_layout" @endphp
@elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 2)
    @php $type = "layouts.employee_layout" @endphp
@elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 3)
    @php $type = "layouts.user_layout" @endphp
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i just transfer the code to my controller then i just compact it. but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@php

    if(Auth::User()->user_role == 1)
        $type = "layouts.admin_layout";
    elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 2)
        $type = "layouts.employee_layout";
    elseif(Auth::User()->user_role == 3)
        $type = "layouts.user_layout";
@endphp
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i just transfer the code to my controller then i just compact it. but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it in a switch:

```
@switch(Auth::user()->user_role)
    @case(1)
        @php $type = "layouts.admin_layout" @endphp
    @break
    @case(2)
        @php $type = "layouts.employee_layout" @endphp
    @break
    @case(3)
        @php $type = "layouts.user_layout" @endphp
@endswitch
```

Switch tend to be a bit more readable when using multiple if/elseif/else statements. Plus you only call `Auth:user()->user_role` once instead of 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i just transfer the code to my controller then i just compact it. but thanks again.